# Why does .sheet(item) Modifier not work inside Toolbar in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, modal-dialog

**Context**

I have a `Menu` (including multiple `Buttons`) inside a `SwiftUI` `Toolbar` and a `.sheet()` `Modifier` inside the `Toolbar`, too.

The problem is, that pressing the `Button` with the `show.toggle()` action does not present the `Sheet` as expected.

> **Important:** I noticed the weird behaviour, that when I give `showOption` an initial value like `var showOption: Option? = .option1`, this works perfectly fine *(except the initial `Sheet` popup of course).* However, once I initiate the `showOption` property with `nil`, it breaks.

---

**Code**

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    var showOption: Option?
    // var showOption: Option? = .option -> this would work perfectly fine.

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Hello World")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Menu { 
                            ... Button(action: { option = .option1 } { ... } ... 
                        }
                        .sheet(item: $showOption) { option in
                            switch option {
                            case .option1: Text("Hello World 1")
                            ...
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Questions**

- Is this caused by the `.sheet()` being inside the `Toolbar` or is there anything else I missed?
- How can I solve this (ideally without moving the `.sheet()` outside of the `Toolbar`)?

Answer (score 1):

if you move it outside of `Menu` (still in Toolbar) it works fine:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var show: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Hello World")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Menu("Test") {
                            Button("Show") {
                                show.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $show) {
                            Text("Hello World 2")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You're right, when adding the `.sheet(isPresented)` modifier to the `Menu`, it works.
However, I've simplified the code above and I actually use the `.sheet(item)` modifier. I have updated the MRE above for you. When switching from `.sheet(isPresented)` to `.sheet(item)`, it stops working. Any idea on why that is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI whenever we apply a modifier to view it actually create a new view with that change applied instead of modifying the existing view in the place. This behavior makes sense: our views only hold the exact properties we give them. Have a look at the sample code below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var show: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Hello World")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Menu("Test") {
                            Button("Show") {
                                print(type(of: self.body))
                                show.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $show) {
                            Text("Hello World 2")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Swift’s `type(of:)` method prints the exact type of a particular view/value, if we add the `.sheet` modifier under the **Menu**, `print(of:)` shows the following output

> ModifiedContent<Text, ToolbarModifier<(),
> TupleToolbarContent<ToolbarItem<(), ModifiedContent<Menu<Text,
> Button>, SheetPresentationModifier>>>>>

Nests the elements in the following way:
Text -> ToolbarModifier -> TupleToolbarContent -> ToolbarItem -> **`ModifiedContent -> Menu -> Text -> Button -> SheetPresentationModifier`**

if we add the `.sheet` modifier under the **button** `print(of:)` shows the following output

> ModifiedContent<Text, ToolbarModifier<(),
> TupleToolbarContent<ToolbarItem<(), Menu<Text,
> ModifiedContent<Button, SheetPresentationModifier>>>>>

Nest the elements in the following way:
Text -> ToolbarModifier -> TupleToolbarContent -> ToolbarItem -> **Menu -> Text -> ModifiedContent -> Button -> SheetPresentationModifier**

So, as we discussed earlier that the order of modifier effect on the functionality of SwiftUI. If we add `.sheet` to the **Menu** element then it  would have additional functionality or appearance that is specific to the ModifiedContent and shows the sheet. While for the case of **button** ModifiedContent does not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You're right, when adding the `.sheet(isPresented)` modifier to the `Menu`, it works.
However, I've simplified the code above and I actually use the `.sheet(item)` modifier. I have updated the MRE above for you. When switching from `.sheet(isPresented)` to `.sheet(item)`, it stops working. Any idea on why that is and how to solve it?

Comment: I updated my question once more since I've discovered some weird behaviour. Giving `showOption` an initial value solves the problem, however, is obviously not great for UX;) Any idea on why that is?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is still the same and it still works, if you move `.sheet` out of the `Menu`:

```
enum Option: Int, Identifiable {
    case option1 = 1
    case option2 = 2
    case option3 = 3
    
    var id: Int { self.rawValue }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showOption: Option?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Hello World")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Menu("Menu") {
                            Button("1") { showOption = .option1 }
                            Button("2") { showOption = .option2 }
                            Button("3") { showOption = .option3 }
                        }
                        .sheet(item: $showOption) { option in
                            Text("Hello World \(option.rawValue)")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, for it's only working with `sheet(isPresented)`. As soon as I replace it with `sheet(item)` it stops working. Have you tested it yourself and it did work?

Comment: yes of course. Preview has problems, but it works in Simulator. Running iOS 16.1 and Xcode 14.1

Comment: I tested it on Simulator and a real device and it breaks for me. I updated my question once more since I've discovered some weird behaviour. Giving `showOption` an initial value solves the problem, however, is obviously not great for UX;) Any idea on why that is?

Comment: Above code work perfectly fine.